# Use CSS to target the image src inside button and replace with another in the Woocommerce Wishlist Plugin for Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, woocommerce

I am using the Woocommerce Wishlist plugin in Wordpress and I want to change the look of the 'Add to Wishlist' button. When I view the source I can see that the button is being styled with a GIF, and I would like to insert my own image into the  to give it my own look. Is this possible? Im not sure how to access and edit html inside a plugin. Or can you change the image src somehow via CSS?

this is my website, and the page I am referring to:

http://www.thecolourmarket.com/shop/sale-items/boho-skirt/

Thanks

Comment: Where is the button?

Comment: Using Javascript / Jquery would be the easiest way to replace the image.

Comment: thank you, the image should appear on the right hand side of the skirt - can you see it? im not really sure how to edit with javascript inside wordpress! its still pretty new to me. thank you for your help though. :)

Comment: I can't see any wishlist button the only button there is the add to cart. maybe you need to be logged in to see the add to wishlist. But anyway If it's the same as Add to card then it's just a css designed button which you can edit easly.

Comment: ok i guess i saw the add to wishlist. you need to hit add to cart first and then it appears which is weird. But you can simply edit the class `.add_to_wishlist.single_add_to_wishlist.button.alt`

Comment: thanks so much, I will give that a try and see how I go! I have no idea why this is happening but the button itself isnt showing up in my chrome browser but is in safari? maybe there is a bug in the plugin. thanks again!

Comment: The button is pure CSS and not an image, as @zouzou0 says you can just add a rule to your style.css in your themes folder, im presuming you wish to change the border radius to match the other buttons on the site?

Comment: Yes thats right, and I want to make it look different (like the 'wishlist' button in the header).  @Rich can you see the button on the page when you look at it? it should be showing up on page load but im not sure if its working properly?

Answer (score 0):

@WPLearner I cannot see it on the link you posted but I can on [this one](http://www.thecolourmarket.com/shop/coats-jackets/suede-patchwork-coat/)

Here is what you need to add to your style.css:

```
.wrapper .wishlist_table .add_to_cart, .wrapper a.add_to_wishlist.button.alt {
   border-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
```